# ignore duplicate on insert

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates, unique

I got 2 tables :

```
CREATE TABLE
p(id_p INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name_p VARCHAR(50),
surname_p VARCHAR(50) 
UNIQUE (name_p,surname_p);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE
t_int(name_int VARCHAR(40),
surname_int VARCHAR(40),
name_m VARCHAR(40),
surname_m VARCHAR(40),
cab VARCHAR(50));
```

I need to move `name_int` and `surname_int` into **p table** on `name_p` and `surname_p`.

My problem is this:
I can't make an unique index for the `name_p` and `surname_p` combination, and on insert I get duplicate error(there are 300k entries). Since I need all of them inserted what should I do?
Insert ignore is not a valid option for me since it is not going to insert them all.

I really need help. 
Thank you.

Comment: This is weird, you want `name_p,surname_p` to be unique, and also you want to insert same value into it. I think you should add a primary key in your first table.

Answer (score 0):

[REPLACE INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) is what you're looking for. It will update records when one already exists, or it will insert a new record if it doesn't exist. This will prevent your "duplicate error" which I assume is a primary key error.